# sending post request javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I'm working on an application that should be sending a post request to an internal page that does a certain calculation

When pressing a button, the page(dashboard.php) prints the content of the other page(calculate_salary.php)

here's my js code so far:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

    function getXmlHttpRequestObject() {
      return new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    var receiveReq = getXmlHttpRequestObject();
    function sayHello() {
      if (receiveReq.readyState == 4 || receiveReq.readyState == 0) {
        var start_date = $("#start_date").val();
        var end_date = $("#end_date").val();
        receiveReq.open("GET", 'calculate_salary.php', true);
        receiveReq.onreadystatechange = handleSayHello;
        receiveReq.send(null);
      }
    }
    function handleSayHello() {
      if (receiveReq.readyState == 4) {
        document.getElementById('span_result').innerHTML = receiveReq.responseText;
      }
    } 
    </script>
```

I want to send over the values in start_date and end_date to the calculate_salary.php page

I will use that calculate page to perform some sql statements and return the result back.

How can I create this request?
POST is not an absolute necessity, I'm willing to use other techniques (js, php) to get the job done

thanks

Comment: You need to change `receiveReq.open("GET", 'calculate_salary.php', true);` to `receiveReq.open("POST", 'calculate_salary.php', true);`

Comment: Is it a must to make that call in plain `JavaScript` ?

Comment: I've changed it to post, It's not sending over the start and end_date

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax instead

```
$.ajax({
    url:"calculate_salary.php",
    type:"POST",
    data:{
        start_date = $("#start_date").val(),
        end_date = $("#end_date").val()
    },
    success:function(response){
        $('#span_result').html(response);
    }
});
```

You can read more about [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) and [$.post](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to generate querystring with url like so:

`var url = 'calculate_salary.php?start_date='+start_date+'&end_date='+end_date;
receiveReq.open("POST", url, true);`

Because you are not sending values that is why you are not receiving values on server side.

Another example you can find here:
[[How do I pass along variables with XMLHTTPRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8064691/how-do-i-pass-along-variables-with-xmlhttprequest)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8064691/how-do-i-pass-along-variables-with-xmlhttprequest)

Also check into this:
http://devzone.co.in/jquery-serialize-function-ajax-post-bigger-html-forms/