# How to send a variable value using AJAX to java servlet? (no jQuery)

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, tomcat, servlets

I am trying to create an AJAX request that sends a string value to a Java servlet.

In the AJAX code I had:

```
    xhttp.open("GET", link, true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhttp.send("foo=bar&lorem=ipsum");
```

in the java servlet that handles the request i tried using `request.getParameter("foo")`
hoping to get the values "bar". How can I get the values within the .send method on the Java servlet?

Comment: You are using the "GET" method. So you must add the parameter into your link : link + 'foo=bar&lorem=ipsum'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass along variables with XMLHTTPRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8064691/how-do-i-pass-along-variables-with-xmlhttprequest)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
xhttp.open("GET", link+'?foo=bar&lorem=ipsum', true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhttp.send();
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that You are sending parameters in the body for the Get request. 
One option is to use Post request and the other one is to send parameter in URL in case of  GET request (This is the answer suggested by Bibek Khadka).

To know more information about JavaScript xhttp methods refer this link

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send

To know more about the HTTP methods
[Http Methods](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp)

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending a `GET` request you have to bind parameters to the URL. And you don't need to set the request header.

```
xhttp.open("GET", link + "?foo=bar&lorem=ipsum", true);
xhttp.send();
```

---

If you are sending a `POST` request you have to parse parameters and the values to the `send()` function and set the request header.

```
xhttp.open("POST", link, true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhttp.send("foo=bar&lorem=ipsum");
```