# How to solve error at xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")?

Tags: javascript, ajax

(I searched a lot, and I could not find this question on Stack Overflow).

Now I'm working on saving a lot of data from HTML to database via AJAX JavaScript to php. Here is my JavaScript code:

```
function save()
{
          var hist = document.getElementById("hist").value;
                var mission =   document.getElementById("mission").value;

 var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
        {
             if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200 ) 
            {

                 UserAccountInfo =   this.responseText;
                 alert(UserAccountInfo);


            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("POST","savecompany.php",true);
          xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlhttp.send("history="+hist+"&mission="mission);   
}
```

The code crashes on

```
 xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

If I commented this line, the alert comes to me with plan string and the Database saved plan string!

Here is my PHP file

```
<?php

    require "conn.php";


    $history= $_POST["history"];
    $mission = $_POST["mission"];

    $sql = " UPDATE company SET history ='$history' , mission='$mission'  where id='1'";
    mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

echo $history;
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Where is my error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like you meant to type `xmlhttp` and ended up writing `xhttp`. That variable isn't defined.

Comment: OOOOH!!!! Okay i works now THank you. 
But I have a new error how can I send params like this         xmlhttp.send("history="+hist+"&mission="mission);

Comment: the answer is on this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8064691/how-do-i-pass-along-variables-with-xmlhttprequest

Comment: This is for GET not POST !!

Comment: ok relax lol. It looks like you're not using concatenation on the last variable.
`xmlhttp.send("history="+hist+"&mission="mission); `

vs

`xmlhttp.send("history=" + hist + "&mission=" + mission); `

Comment: okay Thank you in works now but it can read part of history content :( not all of them and can't read mission at all !!

Comment: @EmanFateen: it looks like your question is answered on this page. While your helper may be willing to assist on small supplementary questions, please (1) try researching new problems yourself, and then (2) ask a new question if necessary.