# PHP-script doesnt return values

Tags: javascript, php, html

i tried to programm a calculator in HTML/CSS/JS/PHP, but i´ve got just "0" as my return value, which i gave the variable "ergebnis" in the PHP code. Normaly the result of a calculation should be display on the calculator screen and the js console.
The HTML code is just the optic of the calculator. In the JS-code i tried to make an ajax-request, but i am not sure, if it works, because i can´t echo the content of them in the php script. But normally it should work, because i got the readystate 4 confirmation back.
In the PHP-code i just want to calculate the carried numbers, but the return value is still zero after run the code.
Hope somebody can help me

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Taschenrechner</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Taschenrechner.css">
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="aussenDiv">
            <div id="zweiteEbeneaussenDiv">
                
                <form action="Taschenrechner.php" method="get">
                    <input id="eingabefeld" type="text" value="">
                    
                    <div class="ergebnis"></div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="delete">C</div>                 
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="button number">7</div>
                        <div class="button number">8</div>
                        <div class="button number">9</div>
                        <div class="button operator">/</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="button number">4</div>
                        <div class="button number">5</div>
                        <div class="button number">6</div>
                        <div class="button operator">*</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="button number">1</div>
                        <div class="button number">2</div>
                        <div class="button number">3</div>
                        <div class="button operator">-</div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="button komma">.</div>
                        <div class="button number">0</div>
                        <div  id="orangeZeichen" class="button">=</div>
                        <div class="button operator">+</div>
                    </div>

                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

    
    </body>
    <script src="JS_TR_neu.js"></script>
</html>

let number1 = "";
let number2 = "";
let orangeZeichen = 0;
let operator = "";
let komma = "";
let ergebnis = "";

//Zuweisung des Operators
document.querySelectorAll(".operator").forEach(element => {

    element.addEventListener("click", () => {
        console.log(element.innerHTML);
        document.querySelector("#eingabefeld").value += element.innerHTML;
        operator = element.innerHTML;
    })
})



//Zuweisung der Zahlen
document.querySelectorAll(".number").forEach(element => {

    element.addEventListener("click", () => {
        console.log(element.innerHTML);
        document.querySelector("#eingabefeld").value += element.innerHTML;

        if (operator === ""){
            number1 = element.innerHTML;
            console.log("Zahl1: ", number1);
        }else{
            number2 = element.innerHTML;
            console.log("Zahl2: ", number2);
        }
    })
})



//AJAX-Request


    //Gleichheitszeichen
    document.querySelector("#orangeZeichen").addEventListener("click", () => {

        let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhr.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200){
                console.log("readystate suceed: " + this.readyState);
                var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText); //Verarbeitet responseText zu JS Objekt
                console.log("Response: ", response);
                document.querySelector("#eingabefeld").value += response;
            }
        }


        xhr.open("GET", "Taschenrechner.php");
        
        var parameters = "number=" + encodeURIComponent(number1) + 
                        "&number=" + encodeURIComponent(number2) + 
                        "&operator=" + encodeURIComponent(operator);
        
        
        xhr.send(parameters);

        
        
    })

<?php
  
    $number1 = $_GET["number1"];
    $number2 = $_GET["number2"];
    $operator = $_GET["operator"];
    
    if (isset($number2)){
    echo $number1;
    echo $number2;
    echo $operator;
    }
    $erg = 0;
    if ($operator === "+"){        
        $erg = (float) $number1 + (float) $number2;
    }elseif($operator === "-"){
        $erg = (float) $number1 - (float) $number2;
    }elseif($operator === "*"){
        $erg = (float) $number1 * (float) $number2;
    }elseif($operator === "/"){
        $erg = (float) $number1 / (float) $number2;
    }
    echo json_encode("=".$erg);
?>
```

Comment: *"i tried to make an ajax-request, but i am not sure, if it works"* - This is a good time to start familiarizing yourself with your browser's debugging tools.  In those tools, are there any errors on the development console?  On the network tab, is the AJAX request made?  Does the request contain the data you expect?  What is the server's response?  Does that response contain the data you expect?  Your debugging goal is to narrow down the specific operation which isn't doing what you expect, whether client-side or server-side.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send: _"If the request method is GET or HEAD, the body parameter is ignored and the request body is set to null."_ - you need to append your parameters to the URL you are requesting.

Comment: What did you see when you checked the Network tab in your Dev Tools, particularly the line representing your request. Are the parameters successfully passed?

Comment: Thanks for your answers.I already tried to figure out, what is wrong with the debugging tools i guess. There is no error on the screen and the JS Script replies the String in the xhr.onreadystatechange function. I think something is wrong with the transmission of the data via ajax, but i dont no what

Comment: Hey Lajos!
I just see "=0" in the network tab of the php data

Comment: Can you create a screenshot of your URL and payload?

Comment: Why is the JS not included in script tag?

Answer (score 0):

You try to use a GET request with a request body, which isn't working (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send for detailed info).

You should try to append your parameters within the `xhr.open` call.

```
 var parameters = "number=" + encodeURIComponent(number1) + 
                    "&number=" + encodeURIComponent(number2) + 
                    "&operator=" + encodeURIComponent(operator);

 xhr.open("GET", "Taschenrechner.php?" + parameters);
 xhr.send(null);
```

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/8064705/4968143

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it still doesnt working :(

Comment: @grotivanhelden you have two `number` variables in the query string, you need `number1` and `number2`

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion.
Instead or if else cascade I think is better to use a switch:

```
$erg = 0;
switch($operator){
    case "+":  $erg = (float) $number1 + (float) $number2; break;
    case "-":  $erg = (float) $number1 - (float) $number2; break;
    case "*":  $erg = (float) $number1 * (float) $number2; break;
    case "/":  $erg = (float) $number1 / (float) $number2; break;
}
echo json_encode("=".$erg);
```